# rspec testing model validations with subject - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rspec

This is my test for validation, i would like to find the best way to writing model specs, especially for validation. But I have problem with this code below.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Ad, :focus do
  let(:ad) { Ad.sham!(:build) }

  specify { ad.should be_valid }

  it "not creates a new instane given a invalid attribute" do
    ad = Ad.new
    ad.should_not be_valid
  end

  [:title, :category_id, :email, :ad_content, :name, :price].each do |attr|
    it "should require a #{attr}" do
      subject.errors[attr].should include("blank") 
    end
  end    
end
```

When I run this spec i receive this error:

```
   5) Ad should require a name
     Failure/Error: subject.errors[attr].should include("blank")
       expected [] to include "blank"
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
       -blank
       +[]
     # ./spec/model/ad_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not calling `valid?` *in that example* before checking for  errors. You're calling it (indirectly) in the previous example, but not the one that you're asserting that has errors.

The correct way is this:

```
[:title, :category_id, :email, :ad_content, :name, :price].each do |attr|
  it "should require a #{attr}" do
    subject.valid?
    subject.errors[attr].should include("blank")
  end
 end
```